# OR operator too slow_should I rewrite to IF_ELSE?

Tags: sql, oracle

So today I have to tune an old procedure. And I go into this query (all columns, table's name had been changed):

```
--Get max date 
DECLARE
    l_col1 varchar2(20) := '11111';
    l_col6 number := 20160131;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO temp_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, MAX(col6) 
    FROM data_table 
    WHERE (l_col1 = ' ' OR col1 = l_col1)
            AND col6 <= l_col6
    GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;
END;
```

This run for 0.25 secs_too slow.

But when I change to IF - ELSE statement the new Query only rune for 0.047 secs.

When I change to IN statement: ~0.25 secs.

`data_table` has index(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)

Data_table now has 1.5 mil rows, and will be increase. Inserted records has thousands of rows(In this case 5k rows).

Could anyone explain and suggest me how should I rewrite the original Query? Use IF-ELSE (duplicate code) or Other way? Thank you.

```
DECLARE
    l_col1 varchar2(20) := '11111';
    l_col6 number := 20160131;
BEGIN
    IF l_col1 = ' '
    THEN
        INSERT INTO temp_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
        SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, MAX(col6) 
        FROM data_table 
        WHERE col6 <= l_col6
        GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO temp_table (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6)
        SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, MAX(col6) 
        FROM data_table 
        WHERE  col1 = l_col1
                AND col6 <= l_col6
        GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;
    END IF;
END;
```

Query plan (for single query with fix code, not declare `WHERE ('11111' = ' ' OR col1 = '11111')`):

OR statement:

[image: OR]

IF statement:

[image: IF]

ELSE statement:

[image: else]

Comment: If l_col1='11111' why check for  ' ' in the first place?

Comment: @Rene Sr I can't generate Query Plan for `WHERE (l_col1 = ' ' OR col1 = l_col1)` so I must hard code for that. `l_col1` is a parameter that pass to procedure.

Comment: Does using a null value make a difference? 
where (l_col1 is null or l_col1 = col1).

Comment: @Rene `(l_col1 IS NULL OR  col1 = l_col1)` run for min time = 0.2 secs, often ~0.21 secs

Comment: How many inserted records are we talking about?

Comment: @Rene Inserted records has thousands of rows. In this case it has 5k rows. `data_table` now has 1.5 mil rows, and will be increase.

Comment: Your timing for the if-else situation. Is that for both a value for l_col1 and an empty value for l_col1? Maybe you a re looking at half the picture.

Comment: @Rene Yes, you're right. If `l_col1` has an empty value then inserted record become ~278k rows, time for `OR` go up to 0.62 secs, time for `IF-ELSE` ~ same 0.62 (could you suggest any way to calculate average running time of query instead of run manually and get average?)

Comment: I assume the driving clause is `AND col6 <= l_col6`. Try `l_col1 IN (' ', col1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, MAX(col6) 
    FROM data_table 
    WHERE col1 = decode(l_col1, ' ', col1)
            AND col6 <= l_col6
    GROUP BY col1, col2, col3, col4, col5;
```

or `union all` statement

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion solve my second question.